# Xcode UI Testing: how to test app's first launching

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing UITests in xCode 7.1 and have a function that tests app during first launching. The question is: how to check does the app launched for the first time or not.
I need something like this:

```
func testFirstLaunching() {
   if ("app is launched for the first time") {
        //test scenario of first launching
     }
   else  {
        //invoke func that will test other scenario
     }
}
```

Does anybody know any trick how to check this?
App is using **NSUserDefaults**, maybe Xcode tests have a super-powerful feature to access it?

Any suggestions would be valuable!)

Comment: I am aware that you can do if statements like this. The question is what to put in the if block. Perhaps you can check for the presence of a navigation bar title. 
```
if (app.staticTexts["My Main Screen"].exists) { do normal app stuff} 
else {assume you are in first launch}
```

Comment: Nice thought, I tried this approach but in my case the problem is navigation title appears after login window (login via network, so this cause some delay), so to check the navigation title waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout) function is needed, and if it is first launching - one window appears (one navigation title), if it is not first launching - another window appears (so we have different static text).
So after timeout test fails if it didn't find right title (and the problem is title is different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a manual solution to your problem:

1. Create a global variable in your first presented ViewController, make it false
2. In your viewDidLoad, change its value to true
3. Save it
4. In `testFirstLaunching()`, read the value of your variable
5. Use the if-statement for doing whatever you want to do

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is the right way of thinking, but I can read NSUserDefaults in the same way. The question is how to get access to it (or global variable in ViewController) via **XCTestCase** class object, or via **XCUIApplication()** ?)

Comment: Access to what? You mean you want to access whether the app has been opened at least once from every VC?

Comment: Hi Linus, Could you tell us more about how you would check a variable from your test code? Does `XCUIApplication` have a way to read user defaults?

Comment: How I solved this: I used global var **isFirstRun** in special **Settings** class in my app (what is actually similar to what @Linus G. proposed, so you got your answer accepted :) ).
The reason of misunderstanding was unchecked **AppUITests** target in **Settings** class (Target membership window in Utility pane), so the variables from that class were unreachable for **AppUITests** class.
My mistake, important reason of issue and good experience for other developers.

Comment: Oh ok, glad to hear you made it :)